# Making a constraint of Maybe a where Eq a

Tags: haskell

How can I constrain to Maybe a where Eq a? It needs to be of kind * -> Constraint

What I tried:

```
class (a ~ Maybe b, Eq b) => K a where
instance (a ~ Maybe b, Eq b) => K a where
```

Error:

```
Not in scope: type variable ‘b’
```

Example Usage:

```
data Test c = forall a. (c a) => Test a
r :: Test K -> Maybe Bool
r (Test o) = (==) <$> o <*> o -- I need GHC to infer that o is Maybe Eq
```

Cases that work:

```
pp :: Test ((~) String) -> String
pp (Test o) = o ++ "X" -- GHC infers that o is a string

hh :: Test Eq -> Bool
hh (Test o) = o == o -- GHC infers that o is Eq
```

Generic answer here: [Is there a general way to apply constraints to a type application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178589/is-there-a-general-way-to-apply-constraints-to-a-type-application/41178590#41178590)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm trying to make a record like thing with a type changing map. It works now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following compiles on my machine. No idea how sensible it is.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
class (Eq (UnMaybe a), a ~ Maybe (UnMaybe a)) => EqMaybe a where
    type UnMaybe a

instance Eq a => EqMaybe (Maybe a) where
    type UnMaybe (Maybe a) = a

data Test c = forall a. c a => Test a
r :: Test EqMaybe -> Maybe Bool
r (Test o) = (==) <$> o <*> o
f :: Test Eq -> Test EqMaybe
f (Test o) = Test (Just o)
```

Comment: Given that there is such a strict constraint `b ~ Maybe a`, it is a bit annoying to have to include both `a` and `b` in the instance head.

Comment: `fj1 :: Test Eq -> Test (EqMaybe b)`
`fj1 (Test o) = Test $ Just o`

Comment: • Could not deduce (EqMaybe b (Maybe a)) arising from a use of ‘Test’
  from the context: Eq a

Comment: @2426021684 Fixed.

Comment: @DanielWagner Very nice! This is the trick dfeuer keeps using (adding the constraint in both directions to facilitate type inference) - I really need to get the hang of this.

Comment: Tiny quibble: there's no reason for `UnMaybe` to be an associated type. I think it's clearer as a closed type family: `type family UnMaybe m where UnMaybe (Maybe a) = a`.

Comment: One more quibble: you might as well make the instance head fully polymorphic as well. This will involve less duplication if you use a type synonym for the constraint.

Comment: @dfeuer Regarding the closed type family: unless you are planning on adding a second catch all case and have it report a `TypeError`, isn't the type family better like this? At you can be sure it will never end up stuck...

Comment: @Alec, it can still be stuck. Nothing stops one from applying it to an arbitrary type.

Comment: @dfeuer Is it possible to generalize this by writing a `((* -> *) -> Constraint) -> (* -> Constraint) -> * -> Constraint` type function?` `(F ((~) Maybe) Eq)`

Comment: @2426021684, I don't believe `~` can be partially applied, but you might be able to make that general approach work.

Comment: @dfeuer It can be partially applied.

Comment: @2426021684, I believe I have a fully general solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178589/is-there-a-general-way-to-apply-constraints-to-a-type-application/41178590#41178590

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known issue](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3490). GHC is choking up because you have introduced a new type variable `b` not mentioned anywhere else in the instance head. One workaround is to use type families and constraint kinds.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecideableInstances, 
             UndecideableSuperclasses, FlexibleInstances
  #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import GHC.Prim (Any)

type family MaybeEq x :: Constraint where
  MaybeEq (Maybe a) = Eq a
  MaybeEq _         = Any    -- A good "unsatisfiable" constraint

class MaybeEq a => K a where
instance MaybeEq a => K a where
```

Comment: I am very surprised that this works. It seems like this ought to allow us to write `foo :: K Int => () -> Int; foo x = x` since `K Int` implies `MaybeEq Int`, which implies `() ~ Int`. Yet it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm working in 8.0.1 right now and I can define such a `foo` without problem (naturally I can't _use_ it since there is no instance for `K Int`). What version are you running?

Comment: `rf2 :: Test K -> Maybe Bool`
`rf2 (Test o) = (==) <$> o <*> o -- I need GHC to infer that o is Maybe Eq`

Comment: Error : `• Could not deduce: a ~ Maybe a0
  from the context: K a`

Comment: @Alec I am also in 8.0.1. When I write `let foo :: K Int => () -> Int; foo x = x` in ghci I get `Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘()’ In the expression: x`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Huh. Something seems amiss. Some clarifications: I'm actually in `8.0.1.20161117`, and I am both able to get the error message and avoiding it (depending on extensions enabled I think?) - still trying to whittle down a minimal test case...