# Is there a general way to apply constraints to a type application?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families, polykinds

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111715/making-a-constraint-of-maybe-a-where-eq-a/41111825?noredirect=1#comment69502706_41111825) by user [2426021684](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6369276/2426021684) led me to investigate whether it was possible to come up with a type function `F` such that `F c1 c2 fa` demonstrates that for some `f` and `a`:

1. `fa ~ f a`
2. `c1 f`
3. `c2 a`

It turns out that the simplest form of this is quite easy. However, I found it rather difficult to work out how to write a poly-kinded version. Fortunately, I managed to find a way as I was writing this question.

Answer (score 6):

First, some boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, UndecidableSuperClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module ConstrainApplications where

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Type.Equality
```

Now type families to deconstruct applications at arbitrary kinds.

```
type family GetFun a where
  GetFun (f _) = f
type family GetArg a where
  GetArg (_ a) = a
```

Now an extremely general type function, more general than necessary to answer the question. But this allows a constraint involving both components of the application.

```
type G (cfa :: (j -> k) -> j -> Constraint) (fa :: k)
  = ( fa ~ (GetFun fa :: j -> k) (GetArg fa :: j)
    , cfa (GetFun fa) (GetArg fa))
```

I don't like offering constraint functions without classes to match, so here's a first-class version of `G`.

```
class G cfa fa => GC cfa fa
instance G cfa fa => GC cfa fa
```

It's possible to express `F` using `G` and an auxiliary class:

```
class (cf f, ca a) => Q cf ca f a
instance (cf f, ca a) => Q cf ca f a

type F cf ca fa = G (Q cf ca) fa

class F cf ca fa => FC cf ca fa
instance F cf ca fa => FC cf ca fa
```

Here are some sample uses of `F`:

```
t1 :: FC ((~) Maybe) Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
t1 = (==)

-- In this case, we deconstruct the type *twice*:
-- we separate `a` into `e y`, and then separate
-- `e` into `Either x`.
t2 :: FC (FC ((~) Either) Show) Show a => a -> String
t2 x = case x of Left p -> show p
                 Right p -> show p

t3 :: FC Applicative Eq a => a -> a -> GetFun a Bool
t3 x y = (==) <$> x <*> y
```

Comment: It looks better if you use FC as an inflix operator.

Comment: `((~) Either) \`FC\` Eq \`FC\` Eq`

Comment: `infixr \`CFun\``
`type CFun a b = (~) (->) \`FC\` a \`FC\` b` Makes constraints with functions much easier